# Is the C++ Standard Library part of the C++ Language?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is the C++ Standard Library *part of* the C++ Language? (*note "language", not "standard"; both are, of course, part of the standard*).

If so, why? If not, why not?

The answer to this question may differ across C++98, C++03 and C++0x.

It's not subjective because it can be inferred from wording/requirements in the relevant standards documents.

Comment: Is this a trick question or a reading comprehension test?

Comment: @HansPassant: It's a question that, in my opinion, would be a good community wiki post.

Comment: It is a very good question - please don't close it.

Comment: Just before the arrival of C++0x. This question is asked at the right time.

Comment: @Acme: Exactly the point. :) Thanks for the added tags, btw.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Define "the language"

Comment: @John: Well that's the question, really.

Comment: @JoeGauterin: Some of us are interested to know precise details of technologies that we use. If you're not, then you don't have to participate!

Comment: @Joe: You removed your answer before giving me a chance to respond. // "this isn't about programming at all, it's quibbling about a minor point of English. " // Absolutely not. Whether the library is part of the language is to do with the _meaning_ of the standard, and has repercussions for freestanding implementations. It's far more than haggling over an English word.

Comment: @Joe: The problem that I faced was that I didn't know the answer to this question; it's answerable hence the good quality answers below; it's practical because, as I've told you a few times now, it has repercussions for freestanding implementations and terse technical documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very first words in all of the versions of the standard I've seen
are "This International Standard specifies requirements for
implementations of the C++ programming language."  In other words,
anything specified in the standard is part of the "language".

In other places, the standard does distinguish between the library and
the rest of the language.  Formally, however, the only real distinction
is that the library is defined in terms of the non-library parts of the
language; i.e. the library defines classes and templates.  The standard
also makes it clear that the library need not be present as a library,
in the form of header files, and parts, or all of it may be built into
the compiler (although I'm not aware of any compiler which actually does
so).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, in both the current standard (C++03) and the new upcoming one (C++0x, which has at last reached the final draft stage so it shouldn't be too long now), the library functions are part of the specification (at least for the hosted implementations). Even freestanding implementations require a standard library, albeit a much simpler one.

In C++03, chapters 17 through 27 deal with the standard library. In C++0x (at least the n3225 draft which is the latest I have handy), chapters 17 through to 30 are relevant.

You can see the standards for C++03 and the current C++0x draft to confirm this. The standards contain both the language proper and the standard library.

From C++03 (which is pretty much the same as C++0x for this section):

> 1.1 Scope [intro.scope]
>   1 This International Standard specifies requirements for implementations of the C++ programming language. The first such requirement is that they implement the language, and so this International Standard also defines C++. Other requirements and relaxations of the first requirement appear at various places within this International Standard.
>   2 C++ is a general purpose programming language based on the C programming language as described in ISO/IEC 9899:1990 Programming languages – C (1.2). In addition to the facilities provided by C, C++ provides additional data types, classes, templates, exceptions, namespaces, inline functions, operator  overloading, function name overloading, references, free store management operators, and additional library facilities.

So you can see from this that the standards authors do make a distinction between the language proper and the library but, for the implementors of the standard and users of the language, the *language* is the whole thing. You cannot call yourself C++ unless you follow the standard and the standard requires both the language proper and the library.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Your reflexes are very sharp...Beat me to it! :)

Comment: Whilst I agree with you, can you demonstrate with firm citations/rationale that "the specification" is synonymous with "the language"? And that "language" doesn't just mean "the language core part of the spec"?

Comment: The citations are in the standards documents. There aren't _two_ documents, one for the language and one for the standard library. There's only _one,_ you either meet the spec or you don't, and the spec contains both the language proper and the libraries.

Comment: @paxdiablo: the latest draft for C++0x is n3242, don't think they changed the chapters.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That statement contradicts your answer. Either the spec contains "the language" and "the library", or it contains "the langage" which contains "the library". I know what the standard doc looks like.

Comment: I didn't say the language, I said the "language proper", by which I meant the non-library stuff. The standard does _not_ use that term. The standard requires the standard library to be part of the implementation, anything less is non-conforming, hence not C++.

Comment: @paxdiablo: i.e. the "core language" components? I know the standard requires the library and language to be implemented, but to what extend could you say that one is part of the other?

Comment: @Tomalak: Is there a practical reason that would make it important to know whether the library is "part of the language" or "separate from the language but defined in the same spec"? Your comments seem to imply there is one... I'd like to know what it is!

Comment: @MartinB: No, not really. I just thought that it was an interesting question. (It _does_ potentially have consequences for anyone implementing a standalone implementation of the language -- this is a standard-defined term describing an implementation that doesn't include the standard library.)

Comment: (Sorry, the phrase is "freestanding implementation". Apparently it must provide a library, even if it's restricted.)

Comment: I believe the introduction is non-normative. But then, I'm not sure whether this needs a normative statement at all.

Answer (score 6):

At least they are not separate!

In several places the language clauses of the standard make use of types and interfaces defined in the library clauses. How could it do that if they were separate entities?

For example the construct

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

uses std::initializer_list from the library.

The new expression

```
char* p = new char[42];
```

uses operator new from <new>.

The operator `typeid` returns std::type_info, a library type.

The core feature dynamic_cast might throw an exception, defined in the library.

Some parts of the library, like type_traits and atomic cannot be implemented as just a library, so they are definitely not separate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can find the Library specified in the C++ Standard. Sometimes, you'll run into term "core language features" to distinguish them from library features, but they are both parts of the language.

[EDIT] Actually, the Standard itself seems to make distinction between the language and the library. From the latest draft of C++0x (1.5)

> Clauses 2 through 16 describe the C++ programming language. That description includes detailed syntactic
>   specifications in a form described in 1.6. For convenience, Annex A repeats all such syntactic specifications.
>   2 Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D (the library clauses) describe the Standard C++ library. That description
>   includes detailed descriptions of the templates, classes, functions, constants, and macros that constitute the
>   library, in a form described in Clause 17.

[/EDIT]

Comment: I know it's in the standard, but I guess what I'm looking for is something to demonstrate/prove that "in the standard" means "part of the language". Does the standard contain "the language" and "the library", or _is_ the standard "the language", which happens to contain "the library"?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Actually I may be wrong - see my updated answer.

Comment: @Nemenja: See this is what I'm trying to get at with this question. :) There's a distinction made, but then the library and the language are inextricably entwined (especially in C++0x, with `ranged-for`).

Comment: Alright, apparently `range-for` no longer requires the library. It uses `begin()` and `end()` if found, then falls back on ADL if not. This means we can define global `begin()` and global `end()` and have `range-for` working in a free-standing implementation with no stdlib. I'm not really sure what the implication of that is w.r.t. this discussion though.