# Why does c++ standard still not include file system and networking?

Tags: c++, networking, filesystems, standards

I have been wondering about this for a while, and haven't found out relevant answer anywhere. So do you have any clue, why the C++ standard committee is not even thinking about adding such an essential features in the future? In my opinion every programming language, in order to be usable nowdays, has to implement these basic things:

1. multi-threading
2. networking
3. file system
4. GUI

I'm glad it has beed decided, that C++11 will have at least threading, but is that such a big deal to do the networking and file system? We all know it is possible, for example boost, so why don't they make something simmilar?

Comment: `"In my opinion"` - The real problem with this question.

Comment: well, what's "networking"? What's "file system"? 30 years ago if you asked that, it'd probably be "let's support FAT12 and banyan vines" or something like that. both of which are utterly obsolete/dead/gone. not everything is TCP/IP, and not everything is ext4/ntfs.

Comment: do they have also ask&answer site?

Comment: [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) should be comming

Comment: @Youda008: Yes, there is a suitable mailing list.

Comment: C++ does not have a "benevolent dictator".  A committee always needs a very long time to come up with a version that makes everybody equally unhappy.

Comment: What about embedded systems that don't have filesystems?  There are many embedded systems that are large enough to use C++, but small enough not to have file systems.  Not every platform has or needs a file system.  Same with networking.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Unfortunately the majority of C++ "users" assume mainstream usage and have no understanding that the world is bigger than that, and that there is value in abstractions. It is up to people like you and I to defend that, I fear.

Comment: Althought community marked this Q as "opinion-based", I found some objective reasons to keep C library small (it is for C, but I assume C++ standard lib considers the same reasons):  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#:~:text=It%20does%20not%20include%20a,NET%20Framework%20provide%20as%20standard.)  _The main advantage of the small standard library is that providing a working ISO C environment is much easier than it is with other languages, and consequently porting C to a new platform is comparatively easy_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does c++ standard still not include file system and networking? Do you have any clue, why the C++ standard committee is not even thinking about adding such an essential features in the future?

No, mainly because that is not true!
**[There are ongoing efforts to define standard support for both](https://isocpp.org/std/status).**

Personally, I don't see why we need any of this in the language itself. One of the main problems with this is you almost inevitably constrain the language to supporting those mainstream desktop computers that are all you're considering (IPv4, FAT32/NTFS?) whereas the entire purpose of C++ is to be an *abstraction* away from practical realities. This is why C++ is so versatile: you can do so many things with an *implementation* when you are not unduly constrained by a *standard*.

As for threading it's already there, and as for GUIs … well, that is rather controversial. You have to define what you mean by that and then you have to define it better than the third party libraries of today and of tomorrow. It's not trivial.

Feel free to contribute to the standardisation efforts rather than simply complaining.

Comment: Maybe not the language level. But it would be nice to have standard libraries that deal with it.

Comment: @LokiAstari: [When I say "language" I include the stdlib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5460541/560648). Clearly this support would be part of the stdlib. I still don't see the obsession with bringing everything into the standard. I think it's ultimately harmful.

Comment: maybe because these are the things you need quite often when programming anything else than scientifical calculations?

Comment: and what does it have to do with current FS or Network layer implementation, its matter of OS, library doesn't have to solve it, it just wraps the right OS API into uniform interface

Comment: @Youda008: That does not override the reasons for keeping C++ abstract. And how hard is it to install a library now, really? And isn't it a good thing that you get to choose between many? There is no benefit in having "yet another library" that just so happens to be enshrined in standard text, and the downsides as explained above.

Comment: @Youda008: _"its matter of OS, library doesn't have to solve it"_ That's not true. It unavoidably drives the design of the API. To do this properly C++ would have to come up with a "one size fits all" Networking/Filesystem support suite, which is _not possible_. Unfortunately they're going ahead with it anyway so you should be happy :)

Comment: As for GUIs, there are embedded systems that don't have GUIs.  There is no standard for GUIs, just take a look at the plethora available for Linux systems and PCs.  Also, there are plethora of companies out there that sell custom widgets.  So, I attend to agree that GUI should not be in the Standard because not every platform supports GUIs.

Comment: We do have conditionally-supported features now. If something doesn't make sense on a particular platform, the implementation can just not support it.

Comment: @T.C. Oh great cos that's really gonna help matters :( (not your fault; obviously)

Comment: Even the filesystem class in the new standard is very very limit compared to what filesystems offer today (sparse files, extended attributes, performance hints, asynchronous access). When you want to do something good like a  file copy you will have to dig deep into the system and all it's supported file systems.

Answer (score 5):

1. Multi-threading [is already in](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).
2. Networking might be interesting to implement in a 100% platform-agnostic manner. It's not impossible though.
3. File system access (i.e. directory enumeration etc) almost made it into the newest spec, but they held it back. They're still working on it (here's a [likely implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental)), but it's probably going to make it to the next version.
4. A full-blown GUI toolkit isn't exacly "a basic thing" and few sane languages provide an actually usable GUI as a part of their standard library.

Comment: I assume (emphasis on assume) that the Networking TS is based on Boost.Asio.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit no need to assume, check out the proposal for the Networking TS as well as the talks related to it and Boost.Asio is mentioned as the starting point for the Networking TS.

Comment: @diverscuba23: I know there's no _need_, but I decided not to take the effort of performing research for free on behalf of the OP (I was busy at the time) and instead elected to make a conjecture, leaving interested parties to confirm or deny as they see fit. Thank you for confirming it.